# CollectionBase no IList implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, ilist, members, collectionbase

Would anyone explain to me why in the abstract `CollectionBase` class (in `System.Collections` which derives from `IList`) it does not have the `IList` members implemented? I thought it was obligatory.

[image: System.Collection.CollectionBase]

Comment: [**It**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx) implements e.g. `IList.Add, IList.Contains, IList.IndexOf, IList.Insert, IList.IsFixedSize, IList.IsReadOnly, IList.Item, IList.Remove`. So what's the question?

Comment: Thats exactly what i am searching for but when i check CollectionBase definition i cant see no IList implementation...

Comment: Where are you looking for the _definition_ of `CollectionBase`? I always look first at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx

Comment: I do check definitions with F12 or Context Menu > Visual Studio 2010 .NET 4.0. U re right on msdn i can see the explicit implementation which i was missing i am confused now why i can't see them in Collection name space here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implements `IList` [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx), so you'll need to cast your `CollectionBase` instance to `IList` to access those members.

```
IList list = (IList)collectionBase;
list.Add(...);
```

Comment: When i check definition for CollectionBase i see non of them they should be explicitly defined in CollectionBase or not?

Comment: @Mikatsu - I'm not sure where you're getting the definition from, but if you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.collectionbase.aspx) and scroll down to 'Explicit Interface Implementations', you'll see it explicitly implements `IList` and `ICollection`.

Comment: i ve added an image on start post why is it different to msdn? i use F12 in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Mikatsu - Explicitly implemented interface methods are private to the implementing class, and Visual Studio appears to only show public and protected methods in the definition.